# Optimistic confirmation with Http API?

Tags: confirmation, httpapi

What is the fastest way for you to confirm a transaction using http API? I want my UI to update as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fast as possible you want to use the "processed" commitment of the web3.js Connection. However, it might not be reasonable depending of what you are trying to achieve, from the documentation:

"When querying the ledger state, it's recommended to use lower levels of commitment to report progress and higher levels to ensure the state will not be rolled back."

For a comprehensive read
https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#configuring-state-commitment